# select certain columns from eloquent collection after the query has executed

Tags: laravel, collections

Using Laravel 5.3, I have a model with the following function

```
public function myData() {
    return $this->hasMany(MyData::class);
}
```

and in my collection I have the following

```
$my_data = MyModel->myData()->get();
```

All good so far. If I `return $my_data` I get an eloquent collection with three items.

What I need now though is to create a duplicate of that collection but containing only three of the fields.

I have tried several different things, each of which return an error. The following is the closest I have got, but this returns an empty array - I assume because the fields are located one level deeper than the collection object.

```
$new_collection = $my_data->only(['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3']);
```

What would be the correct way to create a new collection containing all three items, each with only the three selected fields?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map):

```
$slimmed_down = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return [
        'field_1' => $item->field_1,
        'field_2' => $item->field_2,
        'field_3' => $item->field_3
    ];
});
```

This will return a new `Collection` with just the values you want. As far as I know there isn't any other method that does what you want, so iterating over every item and selecting the fields this way is one of the few solutions.

The advantage of using `map` instead of a standard `foreach` loop is that when you use `map` it returns a new instance of `Collection`.

**Edit:**

After some thoughts and research about this, the problem you'll have created is that the all the values in the `Collection` aren't instances of anything anymore. If you don't mind this effect, an even prettier and faster way would be to do this:

```
$slimmed_down = $collection->only(['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'])->toArray();
```

This basically has the same result.

Comment: You can't call `only` on the result of `toArray()`. as it is an array, not a Collection.

Comment: @Kabelo2ka, your edit fixes one problems but adds another - it changes the collection into an array.

Answer (score 5):

Using Laravel 9, I just had the same issue :

> $my_data->only(['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3']);

returning an empty array.
I solved it with :

```
$my_data->map->only(['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3']);
```

Comment: Confirmed this works with Laravel 8 as well, when the other solutions didn't.